# dotnet ef --update-database "Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.dll" exception

Tags: entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

I got this exception:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

after executing "dotnet ef --update-database"

> dotnet --info :
>
> .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003121)
>
> Product Information:
>
> Version:            1.0.0-preview2-003121
>
> Commit SHA-1 hash:  1e9d529bc5
>
> Runtime Environment:
>
> OS Name:     Windows
>
> OS Version:  10.0.10586
>
> OS Platform: Windows
>
> RID:         win10-x64

Any idea? thank you.

Comment: Since it seems you got your answer, would you consider posting it as answer here and then accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an ansfer to my question here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5934#issuecomment-229939582